# Adding headers to sublists

Tags: list-manipulation

I would like to transform the following list:

```
data = {{0, A1, 1}, {1, C1, 2}, {1, C2, 3}, {3, C4, 1}, {0, A2, 1}, {1, C2, 1},
        {0, A1, 4}, {1, C1, 1}, {2, C2, 1}}
```

into another list like this:

```
output = {{A1, 1, 0, A1, 1}, {A1, 1, 1, C1, 2}, {A1, 1, 1, C2, 3}, {A1, 1, 3, C4, 1},
          {A2, 1, 0, A2, 1}, {A2, 1, 1, C2, 1}, {A1, 4, 0, A1, 4}, {A1, 4, 1, C1, 1},
          {A1, 4, 2, C2, 1}}
```

Basically, the first column indicates the level, 0 being the head level of a bill of material and would like to put the header item and header quantity as columns besides the components for easier computation further along.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first thing you should do is collect all the elements under a single header into their own sublists. Assuming the "levels" are always in increasing order, this will do the job:

```
sublists = Split[data, First@#1 <= First@#2 &]
(* {{{0, A1, 1}, {1, C1, 2}, {1, C2, 3}, {3, C4, 1}},
    {{0, A2, 1}, {1, C2, 1}},
    {{0, A1, 4}, {1, C1, 1}, {2, C2, 1}}} *)
```

Then for each sublist, you can just take its header and join it to all its elements.

```
formatted = Function[list, Join[Rest@First@list, #] & /@ list] /@ sublists
(* {{{A1, 1, 0, A1, 1}, {A1, 1, 1, C1, 2}, {A1, 1, 1, C2, 3}, {A1, 1, 3, C4, 1}},
    {{A2, 1, 0, A2, 1}, {A2, 1, 1, C2, 1}},
    {{A1, 4, 0, A1, 4}, {A1, 4, 1, C1, 1}, {A1, 4, 2, C2, 1}}} *)
```

In the end you probably also want to flatten the sublists.

```
output = Flatten[formatted, 1]
(* {{A1, 1, 0, A1, 1}, {A1, 1, 1, C1, 2}, {A1, 1, 1, C2, 3}, {A1, 1, 3, C4, 1},
    {A2, 1, 0, A2, 1}, {A2, 1, 1, C2, 1}, {A1, 4, 0, A1, 4}, {A1, 4, 1, C1, 1},
    {A1, 4, 2, C2, 1}} *)
```

Of course, all of this can be pulled into a single expression if you prefer:

```
output = Flatten[
  Function[list, Join[Rest@First@list, #] & /@ list] /@ 
   Split[data, First@#1 <= First@#2 &], 1]
```

Answer (score 3):

Guessing the "header" data from the two lists in your question, and making non-numeric elements strings,

```
data = {{0, "A1", 1}, {1, "C1", 2}, {1, "C2", 3}, {3, "C4", 1}, {0,"A2", 1}, 
{1, "C2", 1}, {0, "A1", 4}, {1, "C1", 1}, {2, "C2", 1}};

headers = Join @@ Map[With[{h = #[[1, 2 ;;]]}, Map[h &] @ #] &]@
   Split[data, Positive[First@#2] &]
```

> ```
> {{"A1", 1}, {"A1", 1}, {"A1", 1}, {"A1", 1}, 
>  {"A2", 1}, {"A2", 1},
>  {"A1", 4}, {"A1", 4}, {"A1", 4}};
> ```

you can use any of the following

```
Join[headers, data, 2]
MapThread[Join, {headers, data}];
Join @@@ Thread[{headers, data}]
Flatten /@ Thread@{headers, data}
Transpose[Flatten[Transpose /@ {headers, data}, 1]]
Thread[Flatten[Transpose /@ {headers, data}, 1]]
```

to get

```
{{"A1", 1, 0, "A1", 1}, {"A1", 1, 1, "C1", 2}, {"A1", 1, 1, "C2", 3}, 
 {"A1", 1, 3, "C4", 1}, {"A2", 1, 0, "A2", 1}, {"A2", 1, 1, "C2", 1},
 {"A1", 4, 0, "A1", 4}, {"A1", 4, 1, "C1", 1}, {"A1", 4, 2, "C2", 1}}
```

Comment: I think the header is supposed to be the latest entry with first element 0.

Comment: @Rahul, I think you are right ...  and that makes it a much more interesting question.

Comment: @Rojo/@kgluger/@Rahul, thanks so much for taking a stab at the problem. Just to give some context, the toy problem below is an overall simplification of importing and processing some ascii dumps of 200+ report. In the files you would have a header structure, and then a list of variable number components, header and components with each with its own field structure. I was successful in manipulating the files and dumping everything into a single list and this is where I got stuck. It is still very difficult for me to get away from procedural language structure,

Comment: which is what I finally used to get things done quickly, but I want to avoid the use of do's and for's in Mathematica.

Answer (score 3):

If what @kguler interpreted is correct, then you could do

```
Rest@FoldList[
  Join[If[First@#2 == 0, Rest@#2, #1~Take~2], #2] &, {Null, "Default", Indeterminate},
  data]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using `SequenceReplace`:**

```
data = {{0, A1, 1}, {1, C1, 2}, {1, C2, 3}, {3, C4, 1}, {0, A2, 
    1}, {1, C2, 1}, {0, A1, 4}, {1, C1, 1}, {2, C2, 1}};

SequenceReplace[data, {g : {0, a_, b_}, k : {Except[0], _, _} ..} :> 
  Sequence @@ Thread[Join[First@#, Transpose@Last@#] &@{Rest@g, {g, k}}
    ]
 ]

{{A1, 1, 0, A1, 1}, {A1, 1, 1, C1, 2}, {A1, 1, 1, C2, 3}, {A1, 1, 3, 
  C4, 1}, {A2, 1, 0, A2, 1}, {A2, 1, 1, C2, 1}, {A1, 4, 0, A1, 
  4}, {A1, 4, 1, C1, 1}, {A1, 4, 2, C2, 1}}
```